# Automatic type conversion for templates with const/non-const pointer types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, clang

Is it possible to provide an automatic conversion for a template class instantiated with const and non-const pointer types?

Specifically, consider the following:

```
template <typename T>
class A { 
public:
    operator A<const T>()
    {   
        return A<const T>();
    }   
};

int main()
{
    A<const int> a1; 
    A<int> a2; 
    // Works fine; invokes operator A<const T>()
    a1 = a2; 

    A<const int*> a3; 
    A<int*> a4; 
    // Fails to compile: no viable overloaded '='
    a3 = a4; 

    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to provide an explicit conversion for types with pointer template arguments? What would this look like in the definition of A?

As a bonus/background question, why does the above work for non-pointer template arguments, but not for pointer template arguments?

Comment: For 2), because `const T` with `T` being `int *` is `int * const`, not `const int *`

Comment: So, what about `const T` and `T const*` means you want to convert `T` and `T*` implicitly into them exactly?  Would you want, say, a `A<shared_ptr<T>>` to implicitly convert to a `A<shared_ptr<T const>>`?  Or if `U` derives from `T`, would you want `A<T*>` to implicitly convert to `A<U*>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of the confusion is the constness of the pointer vs the constness of the pointee. The setup you have now converts a `T` into a `const T`. If you substitute `int` for `T` it works, `int` becomes `const int`. However, if you substitute `int *` you get `int * const`, not `const int *`. The `T` gets a `const`, which is a pointer, so the pointer becomes `const`, not the object pointed to.
The following code works:

```
A<int*const> a5;
A<int*> a6;
// compiles
a5 = a6;
```

You can do some tricky things like

```
operator A<std::add_pointer_t<std::add_const_t<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>>>()
{
    return {};
}
```

to make `a3 = a4;` compile, but you have to be very careful that these conversions actually do what they are supposed to do (the above example incorrectly(?) allows `int` to `const int *` conversion because `remove_pointer` does nothing if the given type is not a pointer, would need to `enable_if` + `is_pointer` which gets complicated rather quickly).

Comment: It might be a better idea to just partially specialize for pointers.

Comment: You probably also want to support `T const* const*` from `T**`, but not `T const**`.  A bit of SFINAE testing might do it.